# Can I withdraw Euros from ATMs in the Republic of Macedonia?

Tags: budget, money, macedonia, atms

In some countries in Europe which do not use the Euro the ATMs still offer a choice of the local currency or Euro.

Since I'm seeking to minimize ATM fees for withdrawing small amounts when moving frequently between countries knowing whether Macedonia is a country that offers me this choice can help me decide my currency strategy for the coming weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this is purely anecdotal but I spent about a week in the Republic of Macedonia, mostly in Skopje but also in Ohrid.

I never saw or head of an ATM that offered withdrawal in Euros as well as Denar so I have to assume **no**.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it is possible to get Euros from ATMs, but I can help you with your general strategy by quoting my Lonely Planet:

> The denar isn't convertible outside Macedonia. Restaurants, hotels and
>   some shops will accept payment in euro (usually) and US dollars
>   (sometimes).

Comment: Good to know! I had trouble with my Serbian money when I arrived in Macedonia until I found a traveller heading in the opposite direction after a few days. Now I know to go to the ATM just before I leave the country and withdraw only enough to pay my hostel bill.